# Maven 2 deploy scp error - how to debug

Tags: java, maven, scp

When running `maven release:perform`, the upload via `scp` to the repository
fails with "SCP terminated with unknown error code."

I am looking for way to debug this.

I tried setting `javax.net.debug=ssl` with
the MAVEN_OPTS environment variable, but this shows no output.
I didn't try `mvnDebug`, this may be overkill.

**Does anybody know which module Maven 2.2.1 uses for the ssh stuff, so I could find
a way to get some log output out of that?**

Ah, btw, platform is Windows XP (no joke :-).
The maven scp upload worked like this for years, no setup change that I remember.

The distribution section in the POM is like this:

```
  <distributionManagement>
    <repository>
      <id>UploadRepository</id>
      <url>scp://reposerver:/path/to/maven-repo</url>
    </repository>
  </distributionManagement>
```

The `maven -e` output is:

```
[INFO] [INFO] [deploy:deploy {execution: default-deploy}]
[INFO] Uploading: scp://reposerver:/path/to/maven-repo/com/example/project/arti/2.2/arti-2.2.war
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [INFO] Error deploying artifact: Error occurred while deploying 'com/example/project/arti/2.2/arti-2.2.war' to remote repository:
scp://reposerver:/path/to/maven-repo: SCP terminated with unknown error code
[INFO]
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [INFO] For more information, run Maven with the -e switch
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [INFO] Total time: 13 seconds
[INFO] [INFO] Finished at: Wed Dec 28 12:08:10 CET 2016
[INFO] [INFO] Final Memory: 25M/60M
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Maven execution failed, exit code: '1'

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Trace
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Maven execution failed, exit code: '1'
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:719)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeStandaloneGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:569)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:539)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHandleFailures(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:387)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:284)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:180)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:328)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:60)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Maven execution failed, exit code: '1'
        at org.apache.maven.plugins.release.PerformReleaseMojo.execute(PerformReleaseMojo.java:133)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:490)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:694)
        ... 17 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.shared.release.ReleaseExecutionException: Maven execution failed, exit code: '1'
        at org.apache.maven.shared.release.phase.AbstractRunGoalsPhase.execute(AbstractRunGoalsPhase.java:89)
        at org.apache.maven.shared.release.phase.RunPerformGoalsPhase.execute(RunPerformGoalsPhase.java:67)
        at org.apache.maven.shared.release.DefaultReleaseManager.perform(DefaultReleaseManager.java:334)
        at org.apache.maven.shared.release.DefaultReleaseManager.perform(DefaultReleaseManager.java:282)
        at org.apache.maven.shared.release.DefaultReleaseManager.perform(DefaultReleaseManager.java:262)
        at org.apache.maven.plugins.release.PerformReleaseMojo.execute(PerformReleaseMojo.java:129)
        ... 19 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.shared.release.exec.MavenExecutorException: Maven execution failed, exit code: '1'
        at org.apache.maven.shared.release.exec.InvokerMavenExecutor.executeGoals(InvokerMavenExecutor.java:375)
        at org.apache.maven.shared.release.exec.InvokerMavenExecutor.executeGoals(InvokerMavenExecutor.java:393)
        at org.apache.maven.shared.release.phase.AbstractRunGoalsPhase.execute(AbstractRunGoalsPhase.java:81)
        ... 24 more
```

Comment: First why are you trying to use scp for a Maven repository...why not using a repository manager like Nexus, Artifactory or Archiva which will handle that via http...BTW: Have you defined the maven-wagon as extension ? Apart from that why using Maven 2? [Maven 2 is End Of Life](https://maven.apache.org/maven-2.x-eol.html)

Comment: scp was simplest to set up! No extra software, no setup. I am running our departments maven repo on my own, so I like to save time by not updating to the "latest and greatest" all the time. Up+running+working and getting my stuff done. :-)  But now I have already considered updating to Maven 3 and the wagon stuff, if only for better Support on SO :-)

Comment: Ah, and not using wagon. Is it available for Maven 2 too?

Comment: Didn't even know for sure that Maven 2 was EOL. Thanks for the link!

Comment: You don't happen to know what Maven is actually executing here, do you? I mean, there is no "scp" on my Windows ... there is putty; what the hell is Maven doing for this "scp" stuff?

Comment: Wagon is available in Maven 2 as well..but I recommend to use a repository manager which is easy to setup which handles all that repository stuff...and is easier to integrate with other software and can be used for other build tools as well....Just use Nexus download unpack, start it, use it...that's it...

Comment: Going to do that. Thx.